# Grouping input fields in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am trying to group my name/number/email field together so I can have one event listener. I want to make it so when the user leaves the input field, it plays the audio. I have tried adding an event to the parent `.infofield` class but it doesn't work for onblur/focus events. I was wondering how I'd approach this in Javascript?

```
        <section class="infofield">
            <audio id="leave" src= "blur.mp3"></audio>

            <section>
                <p class ="name">Name*</p>
                First: <br><input type="text" name="fname" required><br/>
                Last: <br><input type="text" name="lname" required><br/>
            </section>

            <section>
                <p class ="name">Phone Number*</p>
                <input type="text" name="number" required>
            </section>

            <section>
                <p>Email*</p>
                <input type="email" name="email" required>  
            </section>

        </section>
```

Comment: use `<fieldset>` &  `<legend>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset

Comment: @MisterJojo I used fieldset and it works for the onclick events but not for the blur/focus ones. I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm just saying that if you want to group field inputs you have to use the fieldset html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any difficulties, what is the problem?

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')
  ;
myForm.in_fields.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(inElm=>
  {
  inElm.onfocus=focusOn;
  inElm.onblur=focusOff;
  })
function focusOn(e)
  {
  WiGo.textContent = `evt focus on ${e.target.name}`  
  }
function focusOff(e)
  {
  WiGo.textContent = `evt blur on ${e.target.name}`  
  }  
  
/* previous version --------------------------------------------------
myForm.in_fields.onmouseover=e=>
  {
  WiGo.textContent = 'mouse is over Personal informations fields'
  }
myForm.in_fields.onmouseout=e=>
  {
  WiGo.textContent = 'mouse is out of Personal informations fields'
  }
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```css
#my-form{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
fieldset {
  width:22em;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
legend::before,
legend::after {
   content: '\00a0'
}
label,input {
  float: left;
  margin: .4em;
}
input {
  width:11em ;
  padding: .2em;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: .3em 5px;
}
label {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  width: 9em;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
label::after {
   content: '* :'
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form">

  <!--audio id="leave" src= "blur.mp3"></audio -->

  <fieldset name="in_fields">
    <legend>Personal informations</legend>

    <label> First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" required>

    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" required>

    <label>Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="number" required>

    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" required>  
  </fieldset>

  <p id="WiGo" >What's going on ?</p>

</form>
```

Comment: The issue is that it works with the mouseover/mouseout event but it will not work with the blur/focus event

Comment: I am unsure if this is right but I think it's because mouseover/out sends the event to the element itself and anything inside it, whereas the blur event only detects the loss of focus from the parent elements. I want to figure out how to target all of my input fields so I can add one event listener to all of them